# Chaining Hadoop Pipes and Normal MapReduce jobs?

Tags: java, c++, hadoop, mapreduce

I have Mapper (C++) - Reducer (C++) - Mapper - Reducer, where the Pipes implementation requires intensive computation, so no way to get out of Pipes.

Any preferable method to chain Hadoop MR jobs written in C++ (Hadoop Pipes) and Java? And how do you package the implementation?

Comment: do you want to tag as C++ rather than C#?

Comment: Thanks Jon! Not sure how the C# got attached ;)